# Ajax get data from mvc3 model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to get data from my Action Result to Ajax.

Here is My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Oku(int id)
{
    var ho = db.news.Select(c => c.news_id == id);
    return Json(ho,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my script in Shared View Index.cshtml is

```
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "Home/Oku",
   data: JSON.stringify([22]),
   dataType: "json",

   success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
   },
   error: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
   }
});
```

But somewhere there is a missing something and I can't solve it. Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting `JSON` data from your action method, Use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, which is a short for of jQuery ajax of GET type with datatype as `"json"`. Always try to use URL Helper method. Do not hardcode it.

```
var someId="33";
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("Oku","Home")/"+someId,function(data){
   alert(data);
})
.error(function() { alert("some error error"); })
```

Comment: Allright but i got some error getJson line where "Oku". It's written that Expected ',' or )' and also what is the point of when i debug code the alert appears true,false,false,false,false

Comment: @FurkanSönmez Did you use the code as it is ? It works fine (i tested). Do you have the someId variable value ? Check whether you missed some brackets.